# incomplete polygon over raster in R

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, terra

I was given a csv file which has lon, lat, z value and I converted that to a raster

```
library(terra)
library(rnaturalearth)

world_shp <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass="sf") |> vect()
my_proj <- crs(world_shp)
   
temp_rast <- terra::rast(temp[, c("lon", "lat", "z")], crs = my_proj)
temp_rast
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 360, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
source      : memory 
name        : z 
min value   :    -77.92158 
max value   :     27.33242
```

When I overlay shapefile on raster North and South America do not show up on the raster. Why is this happening?

```
terra::plot(temp_rast)
terra::plot(world_shp, add = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data have global longitude from 0 to 360 instead of the (more) conventional -180 to 180. To fix that you can do

```
r <- rotate(temp_rast)
```